# How to write file to Oculus Quest internal storage

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

I am trying to write a .csv file to save the user's actions and collect it later from the device. I have tried on my computer and it works but I can't seem to get it to work in the Oculus Quest.

My code goes like:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter($"{Application.persistentDataPath}/{_fileName}"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(metrics);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the base path `/mnt/sdcard/`. So you will get something like:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter($"/mnt/sdcard/{_fileName}"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(metrics);
}
```

To allow your program to use the internal storage you need to properly configure the `Build Settings`. This can be done by going to `File->Build Settings->Player Settings...->Other Settings->Write Permissions` and change it to `External(SDCard)` (I did this in Unity 2018.4.11f1)

Also, beware when running the application on your device, if no pop-up asking for write permission shows up try going to Library to run your application again.